# Why use the word "invalidate" to request a view to be redrawn?

Tags: android, user-interface

In GUI, when a view is required to be redraw. We usually do this as follows:

```
View v = View (); 
v.invalidate()
```

I have no idea that the operation "invalidate()" is  such named.  In English, "invalidate" means to make something not valid. But "invalidate a view" in GUI programming is meant to make the view to be redrawn.  I am not a native English speaker. Please give me hints. Tks.

Comment: The point is that the Android API does not want to call it redraw() because that implies that the redraw will happen immediately (inside the function itself). Whereas by saying invalitade() you know that the view will be redrawn as soon as the Android system libraries get around to it. Calling it invalidate instead of redraw is a much better naming convention because it is more precise with regards to what the function is actually doing.

Answer (score 14):

To "invalidate a view" means that any data that may already be drawn is no longer valid. The view of the data is invalid, hence `invalidate()` to mark it as such. It's less that the function is making it invalid so much as it is already invalid, but no-one except the caller to `invalidate()` knows that yet. The purpose of the function is to tell the rest of the code that the views data is now invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Invalidate is semantically different from redrawing in that it usually only marks something to be redrawn later, as opposed to redrawing at call-time. The idea is that when several possibly overlapping areas are invalidated, the amount of redrawing at a later time can then be made equal to only the sum of non-overlapping areas. That is, we may redraw only once for several subsequent invalidations. Hence the distinction between redrawing and invalidation exists.